# Set d:DesignInstance in XAML for DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have a `UserControl` with a design `DataContext`:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance designtime:DesignViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

It works pretty fine. Now I have `DataGrid`s with an `ItemsSource` Binding to some collections with specific Types.

My problem are the `DataGridColumn`. For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OrderedPositions}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PositionDefinitionId}" />
```

I thought when I have the `ItemsSource="{Binding OrderedPositions}"`, it's clear, that `PositionDefinitionId` is a `PropertyItem` of the `OrderedPositions` collection. But it's not.

Now I must the `d:DesignInstance` explicitly set, in each `DataGridColumn`! But that's not a nice solution:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PositionDefinitionId}"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance system:Position,
        IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" />
```

In which Position is my specific Type of the `OrderedPositions` collection. Is there a way to work around this problem? So that I do not have to set the `d:DataContext` explicitly in each column?

Comment: Good question :-). I don't think there's a solution. My question would be: How to make a list control (like DataGrid) in a way that the item template is typed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly implement the `DataTemplate` for the `CellTemplate` of the `DataGridTextColumn` then you will be able to define the design time instance, e.g. the following example is for a telerik GridViewDataColum (the fact it is a telerik example is irrelevant):

```
<tel:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Code, Mode=OneWay}">
    <tel:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ca:MessageViewModel}"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Code, Mode=OneWay}"
                       ToolTip="{Binding Path=CodeText, Mode=OneWay}">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </tel:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</tel:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: My intention would be to not have to specify for each column, the design ViewModel. But in the listed solution, I would have to re-do it anyway. I have a possibly solution in mind, to set the design DataContext in code-behind. But I still do not know how it could work.

Comment: why are trying to set design instance for everything, is it becuasse you're using Blend?

Comment: I have many ReSharper warning because the bindings can not be resolved. Also ReSharper->Inspect->Code Issues ... provides lots of warnings, for the same reason

Comment: they don't affect the actual application when it is running only in the IDE. I ususally set the design instance for my DataTemplates but in the scenario you describe I don't - it is only a resharper warning...

Comment: Yes, it is only a resharper warning. But you can not be sure, if this warning is issued because Resharper does not recognize the DataContext, or wel your binding target is really wrong!
If you refactor your application, you can potentially lost a part of binding targets. If the application was refactored by someone else, the danger is even lot bigger.

Comment: yes, but any refactoring that breaks a xaml binding will generate a  xaml binding exception which will be shown in visual studio output window, I presume you don't have any binding expressions errors anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62688/discussion-between-peter70-and-awkwardcoder).

Comment: It's not just Resharper. I see the same with Visual Studio 2017 without Resharper installed. It's only a design time issue, but it's an issue regardless. Another solution may be though to define d:DataContext on the DataGrid element itself with Type set to the type that the columns are binding to properties of. This has worked for me.

Comment: Is there any other ways to do this? I rather not having to specify a custom template for every column just to get rid of the binding warning. I don't want to ignore it either as I want it show up in my Find All Usages/References result as well as getting auto-renamed when I rename the source property.